# QCharts Second Y Axis on the Right Side

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qchart

I want to place a second `ValueAxis` on the right side of a `ChartView`. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtcharts-overview.html#axes) states that "The axes can be placed down, up, left, or right of the chart."

However I find no property in the documentation of `AbstractAxis`, `ValueAxis` or `ChartView` that accords to this. Only the `alignment` property of `AbstractAxis` drew my attention, however it is const and can not be modified in QML:

`Invalid property assignment: "alignment" is a read-only property`

I can see that there is a C++ way to set the alignment in the [Multiple Axes Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtcharts-multiaxis-example.html), but I am looking for a QtQuick way to set the alignment. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use appropriate properties of series instead of axis, for example:

```
ValueAxis {
    id: axisX
}
ValueAxis {
    id: axisY
}
LineSeries { // axes are right-bottom
    axisX: axisX
    axisYRight: axisY
}
LineSeries { // axes are top-left
    axisXTop: axisX
    axisY: axisY
}
```

And yes, I agree that `alignment` is misleading and that would be clearer to set axis using this property.